# Building Ruby Documentation for Java Classes/Source

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, rdoc

As I've recently started using JRuby, more specifically building Java applications using Ruby code, I've started using Java Libraries such as LWJGL and Slick.

I know JRuby changes Java method names to a more ruby-esque structure, my question is, is there any current way to generate Ruby documentation, either from source or by conversion of current documentation or even based on what JRuby exposes the methods themselves as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point when JRuby 1.6.7 is out I plan on cleaning this really rough project for just such a thing:

https://github.com/enebo/noridoc

The intention is it will weave both Java and Ruby syntax together and give reasonable documentation for a Rubyist wanting to know all Ruby methods.  In it's current form you should be able to generate a reasonable set of HTML docs of Java code showing you all ruby aliased methods.  You will need to screw around with the javadoc comment.

Oh and we plan on making this tool available out of the box in JRuby once it is good enough to merge.